# unable to create opengl 3.4 context

Tags: c++, opengl, driver

When I compile the example program from the opengl programming guide redbook version 8, it does run but just brings up a cmd screen saying "unable to create opengl 3.4 context." I have updated my drivers (I have AMD). 7000 series i think. Anyways, Any ideas on how to get past this?

Answer (score 4):

> unable to create opengl ***3.4*** context
>
> Any ideas on how to get past this?

Use a real OpenGL version.  Like 3.3.  Or 4.0.

There never was a 3.4.

Comment: `Use a real OpenGL version` Don't know why but it makes me laughing!

Comment: @Cole-Peterson Whenever you feel frustrated and lost, look at [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/) or [other useful stuff at opengl.org](http://www.opengl.org/resources/). It's a concentrated juice of knowledge about OpenGL.